# Waze intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, waze

I'm tried to write code that open Waze with address , its worked fine 10 month but  now its just open Waze and not give me navigate , code below

```
            String uri = "geo:0,0?q=" + selectedName;

            Uri u = Uri.parse(uri);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,u);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose Navigation Software"));
```

(Don't forget thats it need to work to just with Waze , Its work also with google maps and moovit).

Please Help me ,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25662853/1531971

Comment: what you think that problem? can you check the code on device and share with me what the problem , (this code worked in past , so why now its not working?

Comment: its not working , what you think the problem

Comment: What have you tried to debug your own code? If it worked with no changes then the endpoint has changed and you need to investigate that. Since you didn't share the failure details, who knows?

Comment: the endpoint is the string , its no matter because the address is dynamicll

Comment: every each time the address is other

Comment: Please see [ask]. The best way to get a question answered is to [edit] it and say what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Remember that you are expected to do your own research and show your results.

Comment: Waze has updated its SDK into few different tools: Deeplinks, Transport, IFrame, Data Feeds https://developers.google.com/waze/